# Use Yaml instead of xml config file on Hadoop with ToolRunner and GenericOptionParser

Tags: hadoop, yaml, config

I'm developping a MapReduce (hadoop2.6) application and I would like to use the `yaml` format rather than the `xml` config format

For example

```
configuration:
  hello: "world"
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hello</name>
        <value>world</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**Is there a way i can tell `ToolRunner`, the parser, or whoever that I'm providing a Yaml file?** (*or this feature does not exist,yet*)

---

Here is the skeleton of the application:

```
public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FractalDriver.class);

    static {
        Configuration.addDefaultResource("fractals-default.yml"); 
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Waiting for that day, I say hello to you {}!",
                           getConf().get("hello", "les gens"));

        return 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new FractalDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Of course if I try this I get an exception:

```
[Fatal Error] my-default.yml:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/SOMEPATH/target/classes/my-default.yml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2517)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2364)
    at ...
```